# Adirondacks winter road open/closed status

Tags: united-states, winter, off-road-driving, adirondacks

I'm looking for a decent source to know winter road conditions for various Adirondacks access roads.

First level of interest would be just what is or isn't being maintained.

A better yet answer would be something that gives me info about current state.

Any good source? I'm not looking for a particular road at this point, looking at a lot of things to potentially explore this winter, and road access or not may influence what I end up doing.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there more to "the Adirondacks" than the Adirondack State Park? If you're only talking about the park, then probably the best source would be to directly contact the regional park office, the park police, or the regional office for the department of environmental conservation (looking at their websites I'm having a hard time figuring out which one).

Comment: Interested in a bit of everything really, but the High Peaks would be interested among others.

Answer (score 1):

Outside of identifying the organization / group that maintains the access roads you're interested in and seeing if they have a web presence, I think a good starting place would be to check out some crowd-sourced info. People who are invested in those areas, or who just like helping out tend to leave comments about a place they just visited. I will say I've only used these resources for hiking purposes, but maybe it could be helpful for you?

[The Hiking Project](https://www.hikingproject.com) is by REI, and is my default go to app, but they have other similar "Project" sites that could be useful in gathering info:

- [Mountain](https://www.mountainproject.com/) (climbing)
- [MTB](https://www.mtbproject.com/) (mountain biking)
- [Powder](https://www.powderproject.com/) (backcountry boarding)
- [Trail Run](https://www.trailrunproject.com/) (obviously...trail running)

Specific/Other Links:

[The Hiking Project - Adirondack Region](https://www.hikingproject.com/directory/8009525/adirondack-region) - [AllTrails - High Peaks Wilderness](https://www.alltrails.com/explore/parks/us/new-york/high-peaks-wilderness) - [NYDEC Adirondack Backcountry Information](https://www.dec.ny.gov/outdoor/7865.html)

Apparently I need 10 or more reputation points to post more than 8 links, so if you are still looking for info, I'm happy to help.